# How to locate changes to code for missing post titles in archive pages in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to restore the missing titles to posts in my categories, tags, search pages.
I vaguely remember changing something but don't know where.  It was a long time ago.

The problem is so bad that if there is no 'read more' button, you can't click on a result to go to the page.

Any tips about how to find where this code change would be located?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you know what the code was there is a plugin called string locator (https://wordpress.org/plugins/string-locator/) it allows you to give a small snippet of code or a call and it will tell you every place that code is found in the entirety of WordPress.

Comment: thanks, I got no idea of the code though.

Comment: @JoeBonner if you have access to PHPMyAdmin or a databse tool you will be able to see what files where changed on specific dates depending on your hosting the length of time these records are kept can vary but if its been less than a week they should be there. thats the only other way i can think of

Answer (score 0):

OK after quite a while of various methods, I re-installed the plugin 'yellow pencil'.  I had made some customizations that the plugin claims to be reversible at the click of a button globally (It didn't delete them).  I found a post title that did appear and then reverted all customizations globally to it on a live category page.  Thank god it all works as it should now!

Thank you to all that tried to help me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).